# MYSQL PHP PDO Getting multiple errors on update

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

can anyone help me with the update please?
I'm getting this error when trying to update.

```
Notice: Undefined index: description in C:\xampp\htdocs\RAPA_TOOL\projects.php on line 60

Notice: Undefined index: dtype in C:\xampp\htdocs\RAPA_TOOL\projects.php on line 66

Notice: Undefined index: targetrfs in C:\xampp\htdocs\RAPA_TOOL\projects.php on line 70

Notice: Undefined index: actualrfs in C:\xampp\htdocs\RAPA_TOOL\projects.php on line 71

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\RAPA_TOOL\projects.php:96 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\RAPA_TOOL\projects.php(96): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\RAPA_TOOL\projects.php on line 96
```

Here's my code. I checked the name of each input text and they're all correct but I'm not sure why some are undefined. On this update page, I also display the values of the selected project ID.

```
<?php

include 'include/connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['Update'])){
         $projectid = $_POST['projectid'];
         $projectname = $_POST['projectname'];
         $description = $_POST['description'];
         $systemsname = $_POST['systemsname'];
         $phasename = $_POST['phasename'];
         $status = $_POST['status'];
         $classid = $_POST['classid'];
         $dtypeid = $_POST['dtypeid'];
         $domainid = $_POST['domainid'];
         $kickoffdate = $_POST['kickoffdate'];
         $endorseddate = $_POST['endorseddate'];
         $targetrfs = $_POST['targetrfs'];
         $actualrfs = $_POST['actualrfs'];
         date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Taipei");
         $today = date(("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

     $phaseqry=$conn->prepare('SELECT phaseid FROM ref_project_phase where phasename=:phasename)');
     $phaseqry->execute(['phasename'=>$phasename]);
     $phaseid=$phaseqry->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


$updateqry="UPDATE project_details SET projectname=:projectname,
projectdescription=:description,
dtypeid=:dtypeid,
classid=:classid,
kickoffdate=:kickoffdate,
endorseddate=:endorseddate,
targetrfs=:targetrfs,
actualrfs=:actualrfs,
projectphaseid=:phaseid,
projectstatus=:status,
lastupdated=:today
WHERE projectid=:projectid";

    $updateresult=$conn->prepare($updateqry);
    $updateexec=$updateresult->execute(array(":projectname"=>$projectname, 
    ":description"=>$description,
    ":dtypeid"=>$dtypeid,
    ":classid"=>$classid,
    ":kickoffdate"=>$kickoffdate,
    ":endorseddate"=>$endorseddate,
    ":targetrfs"=>$targetrfs,
    ":actualrfs"=>$actualrfs,
    ":phaseid"=>$phaseid,
    ":status"=>$status,
    ":today"=>$today,
    ":projectid"=>$projectid));

    if($updateexec)
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Successfully Updated..')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('projects.php', '_self')</script>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Data Not Updated!';
    }
  }

   ?>
```

If someone can direct me to resolve the problem, that will be great.
Thanks!

Comment: which is line 96 in this code?

Comment: @ Your Common Sense this line: $phaseqry->execute(['phasename'=>$phasename]);

Comment: regarding PDO, it tells you there is an extra ) in the query. and regarding undefined index refer to the linked post